# Google smart home "sync" intent through user invocation

Tags: google-smart-home

Is it possible to have user send the sync request intent through invocation when a new device is added to the system or "requestSync" is the only way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user is able to trigger a sync themselves by giving the query "sync my devices".

But it's still preferred to support request sync for a more seamless user experience.